# Can we think about Neo4j as in-memory database?

Tags: neo4j

Given the fact that page cache is about mirroring storage files in memory, and given that we have huge amount of memory we can conclude that Neo4j is in-memory database. 
What do you think? Neo4j is in-memory?

Comment: Not if it’s not in-memory, no—caching is different than being in-memory, e.g., if I have 128G RAM and my entire MySQL DB is a gig, is MySQL and in-memory DB? I’d say no, but how you answer that question determines your answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, an in-memory database is a broad term. I won't try to provide a precise definition.

If you are looking for a graph database where the data is primarily stored in main memory, you can take a look at [Memgraph](https://memgraph.com) (DISCLAIMER: I'm the co-founder and CTO). [Memgraph](https://memgraph.com) is a high-performance, in-memory transactional graph database and it's openCypher and Bolt compatible.